# pyqtgraph disable parent widget scrolling while mouse hovering on/is used from sub-widget

Tags: python, scroll, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I have a `QTreeWidget` which I have populated with two sub-widgets a `pyqtgraph.TableWidget()` and a `pyqtgraph.ImageView()`. Now the issue that I have is that when my mouse is within the `ImageView` it is used to apply different actions (e.g. zoom in/out, etc) but this affects the scrolling of the `QTreeWidget`. What I would like to do is to disable the scrolling of the `QTreeWidget` when my mouse is within (hovering?) the `ImageView` boundary and is used for the `ImageView` functionality. Is that possible?

Here is some code snippet of my widget structure:

```
# Tree
self.tree_widget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
self.tree_widget.setHeaderLabels(["Key", "Value", "Image"])
root_item = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(["Test Item"])
self.tree_widget.addTopLevelItem(root_item)

# Data
val=numpy.random.normal(size=(32, 24, 3))

# Sub-widgets
tableWidget = pyqtgraph.TableWidget(sortable=False)
tableWidget.setData(val)

im1 = pyqtgraph.ImageView()
im1.setImage(val.T)

self.tree_widget.setItemWidget(root_item, 1, tableWidget)
self.tree_widget.setItemWidget(root_item, 2, im1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear what mouse events you're having issues with, as the only thing I could think of is wheel events.

If that's the case, just create a subclass of ImageViewer and set as accepted all wheel events it receives: in this way, ImageViewer will work as expected but wheel events won't be propagated to the parent widget (the tree):

```
class MyImageView(pyqtgraph.ImageView):
    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()

    # you can do the same with other mouse events, if that's your issue too
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()

class YourWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        [...]
        im1 = MyImageView()
```