# wheelEvent not being called in latest pyqt5 when using a plot with pyqtgraph

Tags: python, pyqt5, mousewheel, pyqtgraph

I'm using pyqt5 to create some sort of an audio editor for my own needs and I need to be able to handle the mouse wheel and mouse clicks and release on the waveform to zoom in or to set a region that will be cut. Here is a shortened code that displays just the Plotwidget.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QWidget, QMainWindow,QHBoxLayout
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
import sys



class MainWidget(QMainWindow):


    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__()
        self.resize(400,200)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)


        self.graphWidget = PlotWidget()
        self.graphWidget.setMouseEnabled(x=False, y=False)
        data = np.random.randn(10)
        self.graphWidget.plot(data)

        myLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        myLayout.addWidget(self.graphWidget)

        centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        centralWidget.setLayout(myLayout)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        #this is not working
        print("mouse released")

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        #this is working
        print("mousepressed")

    def wheelEvent(self,event):
        #this is not working
        print("wheelevent?")

def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWidget()

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

window()
```

I know that some of these features are already built in pyqtgraph, but some are not working well for me. For example, the vertical zoom uses the pointer as the origin instead of 0 and does not keep a vertically symmetric view as it should be for audio waveform representation. Another example is that even though I was able with proxies and eventfilters to get the mouse position, I was not able to detect the mouse release and thus could not create a rectangular section using a ROI, I could start it but never let it go of my cursor.

Just some additional info, the mouse wheel WAS working properly with a previous version of pyqt5 and pyqtgraph (not the mouse release though), but I had to install everything a new machine and it does not work anymore... I'm using PYQT5.15.6 and PyqtGraph0.12.4

I strongly suspect I have to create an event filter somewhere, but I have ran out of options on where... the Plotwidget, the plotitem inside it, nothing works...

Does someone have an idea to get access to the mouse events again on that small example?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the solution in another question here: [pyqtgraph disable parent widget scrolling while mouse hovering on/is used from sub-widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56707282/pyqtgraph-disable-parent-widget-scrolling-while-mouse-hovering-on-is-used-from-s)

If I just create a subclass of the plotwidget first and create all the events in it, it works perfectly!

Here is the code in case it helps someone else.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QWidget, QMainWindow,QHBoxLayout
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
import sys

class MyPlotWidget(pg.PlotWidget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def wheelEvent(self,event):
        #this works
        print("wheel event")
    
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        #this works
        print("mouse released")

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        #this works
        print("mousepressed")

class MainWidget(QMainWindow):


    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__()
        self.resize(400,200)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)


        self.graphWidget = MyPlotWidget()
        self.graphWidget.setMouseEnabled(x=False, y=False)
        data = np.random.randn(10)
        self.graphWidget.plot(data)

        myLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        myLayout.addWidget(self.graphWidget)

        centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        centralWidget.setLayout(myLayout)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        #this is not working
        print("mouse released")

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        #this is working
        print("mousepressed")

    def wheelEvent(self,event):
        #this is not working
        print("wheelevent?")

def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWidget()

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

window()
```

There is not even a need for event filters or proxies...